# What type of contractor would I hire to level a concrete floor?

Tags: concrete, flooring

I am doing some renovations, and I've recently uncovered an original concrete floor that I would like to have leveled for carpet to be installed. It's currently sloped from level with the adjoining floor to about 2 inches below the joining floor. I'm guessing it will need some type of self leveling concrete material. I would prefer to have a professional take care of it, I'm just not sure who to contact.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that you should dive a bit deeper and resolve the root cause of your problem. 2" of subsidence seems to indicate a bit more work than simply using a self leveling material, you have support/foundation problems. Consult a professional foundation remediation contractor to see if you can get an idea of what the cause is. I would hate to see you "level" it only to have it rise or subside again, undoing your work and money.

Answer (score 1):

It can be hard to find someone to do specialty work like this.  Typically when it is a specialized project, you simply need to find a sub who can complete the task proficiently.  This may be a concrete contractor (larger areas), a flooring contractor (smaller areas), or a general contractor who has an arsenal of subs that they are familiar with and could match your needs to the right sub.  It could even be a handyman if they were proficient in the area of putting in non-shrink grout with a self leveling compound over it.

The point is you are unlikely to find a concrete leveling contractor.  You can, however, find a sub who can level your floor by simply making calls, asking questions, and meeting people onsite.

The trick is making sure they know what they are doing by asking them about their process and why they do it that way. Since there a multiple ways to skin the job, after a few people you should have a feel for who is the best fit for the job.